# Automating Enter PEM pass phrase: in python script

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I have a python script that creates ssl context and that is used in websockets.connect like:
async with websockets.connect(serviceURL,ssl=ssl_context) as websocket:

When above code is executed it prompts for PEM pass phrase.
I need to enter pem pass phrase value programmatically form same python script.

Could you pls suggest if the is a way to achieve the same?

I tried something like:

```
    child = pexpect.spawn('async with websockets.connect(serviceURL,ssl=ssl_context) as websocket:')

    child.expect('Enter PEM pass phrase:')
    child.sendline('ggadmin123')
```

Still it is asking for passphrase.
Enter PEM pass phrase:

Comment: Pls let me know if there is a way to fix this.